# $e$ in Roth's Theorem

Tags: transcendental-numbers

THEOREM 1.8 of the book *Making Transcendence Transparent* by Burger says:
[image]
then it says:
[image]

But $e$ is not algebraic how it satisfies Roth's Theorem ?

Comment: Roth's Theorem says that such a constant can be found for algebraic numbers, not that it can't be found for non-algebraic numbers.

Comment: Please [don't post text as images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155600/259305).  Images aren't shortcut to typing math. [Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The theorem states that IF $\alpha$ is algebraic, THEN [something holds].

It does not state that IF [the same something holds for some number $\beta$] THEN $\beta$ is algebraic.

Answer (score 2):

Consider:

> - For every algebraic number $\alpha$ we have that $q^2 \ge 0$.
> - We can show that $e^2 \ge 0$.

Is there a problem? No. Likewise there is no issue with the statement you quote.

In fact, almost all real numbers satisfy the property in question. It can still be interesting to establish it for specific ones.